# bring line plot to front of bar plot

Tags: r

I have a line and a bar plots in the same graph. However, the bar plot is in the front of the line plot. How can I send the line plot to the front?

```
h<-hist(loose_All, breaks="FD", plot=FALSE)
xfit<-seq(min(loose_All),max(loose_All),length=100)
x.norm<-rnorm(n=100000, mean=mapply("[", results[1], 1),
         sd=mapply("[", results[1], 2))
yfit<-dnorm(xfit,mean=mean(x.norm),sd=sd(x.norm))
yfit <- yfit*max(h$counts)/max(yfit)
plot(xfit*1.1, yfit*1.1, col="blue", lwd=2, type="l", xlab="Looseness",
 main="Normal pdf and histogram",)
plot(h, add=TRUE, col="grey",freq=TRUE)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:
   par(new=TRUE)
   plot(data, function,
     axes = FALSE, xlab = "", ylab = "")

Comment: shorter: `lines(data, function)`